# link to explicit_bzero (glibc) in static library

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I'm porting a windows C++ project to linux. This project has many static libraries which are after used in some shared libraries. One of the static libraries uses SecureZeroMemory, which is a windows specific method to securely zero arrays. To use such function in linux I wrote the following

```
#ifdef __linux__
#include <strings.h>
extern "C" void explicit_bzero(void *s, size_t n);
void SecureZeroMemory(void *s, size_t n) { explicit_bzero(s, n); }
#endif
```

the static library that uses this compiles fine with no errors. My CMakeLists.txt file is pretty standard, after adding the sources etc I do

```
add_library( myStaticLibrary STATIC ${source_files} )
```

and it compiles fine.

Then, I try to compile a shared library that uses the one just mentioned, in another CMakeLists.txt file which is also pretty standard

```
add_library( mySharedLibrary  SHARED ${source_files} )
target_link_libraries(mySharedLibrary c myStaticLibrary  )
```

when compiling I get the error:

```
myShareLibraryCode.cpp:XX undefined reference to `explicit_bzero'
ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Why the separate declaration? Why not just `#include <string.h>` ? (and it looks like it's string singular for explicit_bzero from the man page). And it was new in 2.25 - is your GLIBC new enough? That was from 2017 but if you're on an LTS Linux you might have something older.

Comment: Yes, the issue is the version. I thought I had a version with explicit_bzero because it is in my man pages, but the man page says it appeared in 2.25 and I have 2.24...

Answer (score 2):

I found about explicit_bzero from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset. After that, I checked the man pages in my machine, and **wrongly** assumed that since I had the man page for explicit_bzero my glibc version was recent enough.

I'm using Debian 9.4 with glibc 2.24. As Rup said in the comments, the man page itself says that explicit_bzero appeared in 2.25. So my glibc is not recent enough.

To find your glibc version follow https://benohead.com/blog/2015/01/28/linux-check-glibc-version/

Since I cannot update the glibc version, now I might have to implement my own explicit_bzero. I don't seem to have memset_s either.

Comment: Some linux distributions have libbsd library - there you could find `explicit_bzero`.